# Algebra question on transformation of an n-tuple to $a = (a_1, \dots , a_n)$ to $(1, 0, \dots ,0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number.  An elementary transformation of an $n$-tuple, of integers $\mathbf{b} = (b_1, b_2, \dots , b_n)$,  is a new $n$-tuple obtained from $\mathbf{b}$ by changing a combonent $b_i$ to $b_i +cb_j$ for some $j \neq i$ and $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Let $a_1,\dots, a_n$ be integers such that $\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_n) = 1 $.  Show that there is a sequence of elementary transformations, transforming the n-tuple $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ to the $n$-tuple $(1,0,\dots ,0)$.

I'm struggling with the how to construct a number $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b_i + cb_j = 1$.

How do you demonstrate, or construct such a number, then iterate to transform the $n$-tuple?

Comment: What about Bezout's lemma to get the $1$ and then the $0's$ just by transforming with the first component(i.e., $1$)?

Comment: I have not encountered that yet in class.  I looked it up on wikipedia and I see that it applies but i'm struggling with this part: given a pair of coefficients $(x,y)$ such that $ax + by = 1$ then for an arbitrary integer: $(x+kb, y-ka)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Ah I see now.  I was (incorrectly) thinking that $x+kb + y-ka = 1$. It is much more obvious now that if $ax + by = 1$, then $(x+kb)a + (y-ka)b = 1$.  Distributing through show that $xa + kba + yb - kba = 1$ which is obviously true given $ax+by = 1$.

Comment: So under what assumptions can you work and perhaps we can elaborate from that. Glad you see the solution using Bezout.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot necessarily make $1$ appear in a single step. There are several possible pitfalls:

- Any pair of entries may have non-trivial gcds. Consider the vector $(b_1,b_2,b_3)=(6,10,15)$. No matter what you do with $b_1$ and $b_2$ you end up with an even number. Similarly, an elementary operation only involving $b_1$ and $b_3$ can only give multiples of three, and operations with $b_2$ and $b_3$ alone yield multiples of five.
- A pair may be coprime, but needs more steps to reach the gcd. Not unlike Euclid's algorithm that, more often than not, needs more than a single iteration.

---

Instead you should work to recursively produce smaller and smaller non-zero absolute values:

1. Select an index $i_0$ such that $|b_{i_0}|$ is non-zero and as small as possible. If the absolute value is $1$, then we are done and can stop this process. Otherwise, continue.
2. For all other indices $i\neq i_0$ carry out a single step of the division algorithm,
   replacing $b_i$ with $r_i=b_i+q\cdot b_{i_0}$ such that $|r_i|<|b_{i_0}|$. Observe that
   $\gcd(r_1,\ldots,r_n,b_{i_0})=\gcd(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$.
3. If all the $r_i$s are zero, then $b_{i_0}$ was a common factor. Working under the assumptions that the gcd is equal to one and $|b_{i_0}|>1$, this is impossible. So there exists an index $j$ such that $0<|r_j|<|b_{i_0}|$. We made progress, and can continue from step 1.

Because you can decrease a positive integer only finitely many times before hitting $1$, the algorithm stops.

---

With the earlier example $(b_1,b_2,b_3)=(6,10,15)$ it would go as follows:

1. $b_1=6$ is the smallest component, so according to the rule in step 2 we transform
   $$(6,10,15)\mapsto (6,10-1\cdot6,15-2\cdot6)=(6,4,3).$$
2. In the next step $b_3=3$ is the smallest, so this time Step 2 calls for the transformation
   $$(6,4,3)\mapsto (6-2\cdot3,4-1\cdot3,3)=(0,1,3).$$
   We got the desired $1$, and are content.

---

After you got that single $1$ to appear, another run of Step 2 makes the rest of them equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling with the how to construct a number $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b_i + cb_j = 1$.

You have

$$b_i + cb_j = 1 \implies cb_j = 1 - b_i \implies b_j \mid 1 - b_i \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note you can have sets of integers where \eqref{eq1A} doesn't hold for any $i$ or $j$. Thus, this does not, at least directly, lead to the solution, so I don't see how to use Bezout's lemma, as suggested in the comments, for proving the general case.

Instead, start with the initial stated conditions, i.e., $n \ge 2$, the $a_i$ are integers, and

$$\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_n) = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

One complicating factor is if any of the $a_i$ are $0$. The [Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties) section of Wikipedia's "Greatest common divisor" article states in the third bullet point

> $\gcd(a, 0) = |a|$, for $a \neq 0$, since any number is a divisor of 0, and the greatest divisor of $a$ is $|a|$.

This, I believe, is well accepted. However, if $a = 0$, then what is $\gcd(0, 0)$? This is not quite so well defined. Later in that same section, the fourth last bullet point starts with

> It is sometimes useful to define $\gcd(0, 0) = 0$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(0, 0) = 0$ because ...

Also, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%280%2C0%29) gives a result of $0$. However, Quora's [What is the GCD of 0 and 0?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-GCD-of-0-and-0) has an [answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-GCD-of-0-and-0/answer/Nicolas-Daoust) by "Nicolas Daoust, Mathematics teacher" which states

> **It's undefined** (not that it would be useful anyway).

I've seen other people also claim it's undefined, but regardless of it being $0$ or undefined, not all $a_i$ can be $0$ for \eqref{eq2A} to hold. If you have $n - 1$ values of $0$ instead, then the remaining value must be $1$ or $-1$. If it's the first value, if it's $-1$ you can make it $1$ with a $0$ value, and in either case you're done. Otherwise, if it's at $a_i, \; i \gt 1$, then for $a_i = 1$, use $b_1 = a_1 + a_i = 1$ and then $b_i = a_i - b_1$ (and similarly handle $a_i = -1$).

If there's $n - 2$ or fewer $0$ values, this means there's $2$ or more non-zero values. If any of them are $1$ or $-1$, then if it's $-1$ you can make it $1$ using another value. If this value of $1$ is not in the first spot already, you can make the first one $1$ using this value. After that, you can get all of the rest of the values to be $0$ using the first one.

Otherwise, among all the non-zero values, you have $|a_i| \gt 1$ for all $i$, so the coprime requirement means $|a_i| \neq |a_j|$ for all $i \neq j$. Thus, there's a unique maximum absolute value, call it's index $i$. Among the remaining smaller non-zero value(s), \eqref{eq2A} indicates at least one is relatively prime to $a_i$. Call this element's index $j$. The [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) states there's unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that

$$a_i = qa_j + r, \; 0 \le r \lt |a_j| \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note the coprime property means $r \neq 0$, plus $\gcd(r, a_j) = 1$. Choose $c = -q$ so you get $b_i = a_i - qa_j = r$. You now have the same conditions as before, but with $i$ and $j$ switched around. Thus, keep repeating the procedure to get new and smaller values of positive $r$ each time while switching $i$ and $j$ at each stage until, eventually, the $r$ will become $1$ (note for it become $0$ means either $b_i$ or $b_j$ was $1$ at the previous stage), so either $b_i$ or $b_j$ is then $1$ at that stage.

As before, you can then use this to make the first value $1$, if it's not already, and the  rest of the values $0$.